# For a tvOS app I'm trying to determine which button is selected, in focus

Tags: swift, focus, tvos

In the function pressesBegan

```
override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        guard let selected = UIScreen.main.focusedItem else { return }
```

I want to find which button is in focus, selected, with the code shown. However Xcode tells me that focusedItem is deprecated and that I should use -[UIWindowScene focusSystem].focusedItem instead. I'm still getting errors. Any thoughts on code that might work? Thanks.